# implement trait on a type

Tags: rust

I want to implement pallet-assets on a type which is:

```
pub trait Config<I: 'static = ()>: Config {
type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self, I>> + IsType<<Self as Config>::RuntimeEvent>;
type Balance: Member + Parameter + AtLeast32BitUnsigned + Default + Copy + MaybeSerializeDeserialize + MaxEncodedLen + TypeInfo;
type RemoveItemsLimit: Get<u32>;
type AssetId: Member + Parameter + Copy + MaybeSerializeDeserialize + MaxEncodedLen;
type AssetIdParameter: Parameter + Copy + From<Self::AssetId> + Into<Self::AssetId> + MaxEncodedLen;
type Currency: ReservableCurrency<Self::AccountId>;
type CreateOrigin: EnsureOriginWithArg<Self::RuntimeOrigin, Self::AssetId, Success = Self::AccountId>;
type ForceOrigin: EnsureOrigin<Self::RuntimeOrigin>;
type AssetDeposit: Get<<<Self as Config<I>>::Currency as Currency<<Self as SystemConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>;
type AssetAccountDeposit: Get<<<Self as Config<I>>::Currency as Currency<<Self as SystemConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>;
type MetadataDepositBase: Get<<<Self as Config<I>>::Currency as Currency<<Self as SystemConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>;
type MetadataDepositPerByte: Get<<<Self as Config<I>>::Currency as Currency<<Self as SystemConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>;
type ApprovalDeposit: Get<<<Self as Config<I>>::Currency as Currency<<Self as SystemConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>;
type StringLimit: Get<u32>;
type Freezer: FrozenBalance<Self::AssetId, Self::AccountId, Self::Balance>;
type Extra: Member + Parameter + Default + MaxEncodedLen;
type CallbackHandle: AssetsCallback<Self::AssetId, Self::AccountId>;
```

in order to use in runtime/src/lib.rs
could you pls help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to implement a trait called Config with several associated types and constants for a pallet that deals with assets. Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1510) for implementation of pallets-assets in the runtime of your code

Answer (score 0):

Please walk through this topic:

https://docs.substrate.io/build/pallet-coupling/

Then you can understand how to use pallet in src/runtime/lib.rs ( Implement specific pallet for Runtime) by using existing implementation or new implementation by yourself

Some resources that you can learn:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-application-logic/add-a-pallet/
- https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/master/runtime/moonbase/src/asset_config.rs#L94